# Odoo 11 modules upgrade - KeyError: 'sequence'

Tags: python, odoo-11

I am porting my Odoo 10 to Odoo 11.

I successfully used open upgrade to create a backup of my database v10 ready to be ported on v11.

I am using python 2.7.15rc1 in a virtual environment for version 10 and python 3.6.7 for version 11 still in virtual environment.

After DB port I am upgrading it with the option "-u all".

After a while I get the following error:

```py
    2019-05-08 14:28:55,513 21385 INFO test_v11 odoo.tools.translate: loading /opt/odoo11/addons/project/i18n/it.po
    2019-05-08 14:28:56,772 21385 WARNING test_v11 odoo.fields: Field res.partner.property_stock_customer with unknown comodel_name 'stock.location'
    2019-05-08 14:28:56,772 21385 WARNING test_v11 odoo.fields: Field res.partner.property_stock_supplier with unknown comodel_name 'stock.location'
    2019-05-08 14:28:56,779 21385 WARNING test_v11 odoo.fields: Field res.company.internal_transit_location_id with unknown comodel_name 'stock.location'
    2019-05-08 14:28:56,807 21385 WARNING test_v11 odoo.fields: Field procurement.rule.location_id with unknown comodel_name 'stock.location'
    2019-05-08 14:28:56,807 21385 WARNING test_v11 odoo.fields: Field procurement.rule.location_src_id with unknown comodel_name 'stock.location'
    2019-05-08 14:28:56,807 21385 WARNING test_v11 odoo.fields: Field procurement.rule.route_id with unknown comodel_name 'stock.location.route'
    2019-05-08 14:28:56,808 21385 WARNING test_v11 odoo.fields: Field procurement.rule.picking_type_id with unknown comodel_name 'stock.picking.type'
    2019-05-08 14:28:56,808 21385 WARNING test_v11 odoo.fields: Field procurement.rule.warehouse_id with unknown comodel_name 'stock.warehouse'
    2019-05-08 14:28:56,808 21385 WARNING test_v11 odoo.fields: Field procurement.rule.propagate_warehouse_id with unknown comodel_name 'stock.warehouse'
    2019-05-08 14:28:56,810 21385 WARNING test_v11 odoo.fields: Field stock.fixed.putaway.strat.fixed_location_id with unknown comodel_name 'stock.location'
    2019-05-08 14:28:56,811 21385 WARNING test_v11 odoo.fields: Field stock.inventory.move_ids with unknown comodel_name 'stock.move'
    2019-05-08 14:28:56,812 21385 WARNING test_v11 odoo.fields: Field stock.inventory.location_id with unknown comodel_name 'stock.location'
    2019-05-08 14:28:56,812 21385 WARNING test_v11 odoo.fields: Field stock.inventory.package_id with unknown comodel_name 'stock.quant.package'
    2019-05-08 14:28:56,812 21385 WARNING test_v11 odoo.fields: Field stock.inventory.lot_id with unknown comodel_name 'stock.production.lot'
    2019-05-08 14:28:56,814 21385 WARNING test_v11 odoo.fields: Field stock.inventory.line.location_id with unknown comodel_name 'stock.location'
    2019-05-08 14:28:56,814 21385 WARNING test_v11 odoo.fields: Field stock.inventory.line.package_id with unknown comodel_name 'stock.quant.package'
    2019-05-08 14:28:56,814 21385 WARNING test_v11 odoo.fields: Field stock.inventory.line.prod_lot_id with unknown comodel_name 'stock.production.lot'
    2019-05-08 14:28:56,835 21385 WARNING test_v11 odoo.modules.loading: Transient module states were reset
    2019-05-08 14:28:56,836 21385 ERROR test_v11 odoo.modules.registry: Failed to load registry
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/opt/odoo11/odoo/modules/registry.py", line 85, in new
        odoo.modules.load_modules(registry._db, force_demo, status, update_module)
      File "/opt/odoo11/odoo/modules/loading.py", line 376, in load_modules
        force, status, report, loaded_modules, update_module, models_to_check)
      File "/opt/odoo11/odoo/modules/loading.py", line 274, in load_marked_modules
        perform_checks=perform_checks, models_to_check=models_to_check
      File "/opt/odoo11/odoo/modules/loading.py", line 152, in load_module_graph
        registry.setup_models(cr)
      File "/opt/odoo11/odoo/modules/registry.py", line 277, in setup_models
        model._setup_fields()
      File "/opt/odoo11/odoo/models.py", line 2426, in _setup_fields
        field.setup_full(self)
      File "/opt/odoo11/odoo/fields.py", line 472, in setup_full
        self._setup_related_full(model)
      File "/opt/odoo11/odoo/fields.py", line 509, in _setup_related_full
        field = target._fields[name]
    KeyError: 'sequence'
    2019-05-08 14:28:56,837 21385 CRITICAL test_v11 odoo.service.server: Failed to initialize database `test_v11`.
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/opt/odoo11/odoo/service/server.py", line 1006, in preload_registries
        registry = Registry.new(dbname, update_module=update_module)
      File "/opt/odoo11/odoo/modules/registry.py", line 85, in new
        odoo.modules.load_modules(registry._db, force_demo, status, update_module)
      File "/opt/odoo11/odoo/modules/loading.py", line 376, in load_modules
        force, status, report, loaded_modules, update_module, models_to_check)
      File "/opt/odoo11/odoo/modules/loading.py", line 274, in load_marked_modules
        perform_checks=perform_checks, models_to_check=models_to_check
      File "/opt/odoo11/odoo/modules/loading.py", line 152, in load_module_graph
        registry.setup_models(cr)
      File "/opt/odoo11/odoo/modules/registry.py", line 277, in setup_models
        model._setup_fields()
      File "/opt/odoo11/odoo/models.py", line 2426, in _setup_fields
        field.setup_full(self)
      File "/opt/odoo11/odoo/fields.py", line 472, in setup_full
        self._setup_related_full(model)
      File "/opt/odoo11/odoo/fields.py", line 509, in _setup_related_full
        field = target._fields[name]
    KeyError: 'sequence'
```

Tried to get more info on this online but couldn't find any detail.
Help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer, there was a module partially loaded, in my case it was account_fiscal_year. It came in the log much earlier, I ignored it thinking that I could manage it later as this would not be linked to that warning, big mistake. 
**Always solve issues in the order they appear.** 
Noted.